# Join Multiple tables (basically the same table) with Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have three tables (didn't create the database). They are essentially the same but with slightly different data, they have Company_Id and Category_Id. I also want to link the Category Name to this table, so I have to join in Category.
Before the join this worked

```
Select Distinct CompanyId, Category_ID From Product1 where Product1.CompanyId = 10
union
Select Distinct Distinct CompanyId, Category_ID From Product2 where Product2.CompanyId = 10
union
Select Distinct Distinct CompanyId, Category_ID From Product3 where Product3.CompanyId = 10
```

This got me a disticnt list of Products and categories based on the product ID.

I now need to add in the category name, to the Category table. I tried:

```
    Select Distinct CompanyId, Category_ID From Product1 where Product1.CompanyId = 10
inner join Category on Category.Id=Product1.Category_ID
    union
    Select Distinct Distinct CompanyId, Category_ID From Product2 where Product2.CompanyId = 10
inner join Category on Category.Id=Product2.Category_ID
    union
    Select Distinct Distinct CompanyId, Category_ID From Product3 where Product3.CompanyId = 10
inner join Category on Category.Id=Product3.Category_ID
```

but that returns
The multi-part identifier "Company.CATEGORY_ID" could not be bound.

Any way to display just the distinct items with the category names from all 3 tables?

(so if product1 and product2 both had a product with Company_ID = 10, and had two categories, it would only show twice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where` goes after the `from` clause.  The `join` keyword is part of `from`, so it needs to go before `where`:

```
Select CompanyId, Category_ID
From Product1 inner join
     Category
     on Category.Id = Product1.Category_ID
where Product1.CompanyId = 10
union
Select CompanyId, Category_ID From Product2 
From Product2 inner join
     Category
     on Category.Id = Product1.Category_ID
where Product2.CompanyId = 10
union
Select CompanyId, Category_ID From Product3
From Product3 inner join
     Category
     on Category.Id = Product3.Category_ID
where Product1.CompanyId = 10;
```

Also, `distinct distinct` might be returning an error.  You don't need the `distinct` keyword, because you are using `union` rather than `union all`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Select distinct CompanyId, Category_ID From Product1
inner join Category on Category.Id=Product1.Category_ID where Product1.CompanyId = 10
    union
    Select distinct CompanyId, Category_ID From Product2
inner join Category on Category.Id=Product2.Category_ID  where Product2.CompanyId = 10
    union
    Select distinct CompanyId, Category_ID From Product3
inner join Category on Category.Id=Product3.Category_ID where Product3.CompanyId = 10
```

this was not tested, but if there is no typo, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this. I think it would be more readable and maintainable to do `union` first and after that join `Category` table:

```
with cte as (
    select distinct CompanyId, Category_ID from Product1 where Product1.CompanyId = 10
    union 
    select distinct CompanyId, Category_ID from Product2 where Product2.CompanyId = 10
    union
    select distinct CompanyId, Category_ID from Product3 where Product3.CompanyId = 10
)
select
   P.CompanyId, P.Category_ID, c.Category_Name
from cte as P
   inner join Category as c on c.Id = P.Category_ID
```

or, if you don't like [common table expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), use subquery:

```
select
   P.CompanyId, P.Category_ID, c.Category_Name
from (
    select distinct CompanyId, Category_ID from Product1 where Product1.CompanyId = 10
    union 
    select distinct CompanyId, Category_ID from Product2 where Product2.CompanyId = 10
    union
    select distinct CompanyId, Category_ID from Product3 where Product3.CompanyId = 10
)as P
   inner join Category as c on c.Id = P.Category_ID
```